# Let $c\in[a,b]$ and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(c)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq c$. Prove that $f$ is integrable and the integral is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Is my proof correct?

Proof: Let $\varepsilon>0$ and consider only refinement of the partition $$P_0=\{ a,c-\frac{\varepsilon}{4},c+\frac{\varepsilon}{4},b \}.$$
This way, 
$$ U(f,P)=\left[c+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}-\left(c-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\right)\right]=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon $$
$$ L(f,P)=0. $$
Thus, for all $\varepsilon>0$
$$ U(f,P)=U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon $$
$$ \implies U(f,P)=L(f,P)=0. $$
By definition, $ \underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f\le\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f $. On the other hand
$$ \overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f=\inf\limits_{P}\{U(f,P)\}\le U(f,P)=L(f,P)\le \sup\limits_{P}\{L(f,P)\}=\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f $$
$$ \implies \underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f\ge\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}f $$
Therefore, $f$ is integrable.

Since for all partitions we have $ L(f,P)=0 $,
$$ \sup\limits_{P}\{L(f,P)\}=\underline{\int_{a}^{b}}f=\int_{a}^{b}f=0. $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. What you proved was that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a partition $P\varepsilon$ (you called it $P$ but I want to stress that it depends on $\varepsilon$) such that $L(f,P\varepsilon)=0$ and that $U(f,P\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$. So, yes, $U(f,P\varepsilon)-L(f,P\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$, but $U(f,P\varepsilon)$ is still greater than $0$; you cannot say that $U(f,P\varepsilon)-L(f,P\varepsilon)=0$.

However, it follows from what you did that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0):\overline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx-\underline{\int_a^b}f(x)\,\mathrm dx<\varepsilon$$and therefore, yes$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=0.$$

Comment: I see, I cannot say that $U(f,P_\varepsilon)-L(f,P_\varepsilon)=0$. But I can say that $\sup\{ L(f,P_\varepsilon\}=0$, right? So, $ \inf\{U(f,P_\varepsilon)\}-\sup\{L(f,P_\varepsilon)\}<\varepsilon.$ And the rest follows from this, is that correct? Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

**Darboux integral**

Clearly, $\inf f = 0$ on all of the subintervals of $[a,b]$, which means that
$$\underline{\int} f = 0$$
It's also clear that $\sup f = 0$ on all of the subintervals of $[a,b]$ which does not contain $c$, and $\sup f = 1$ otherwise. If $\delta$ is the norm of the partition, then we have that
$$0\leqslant U \leqslant 2\delta$$
So we can construct a sequence of partitions for which the norm of the partitions will go to zero, i.e. $\delta_n \to 0$, so for their upper Darboux sum, we will have that
$$0 \leqslant U_n \leqslant 2\delta_n$$
Which means that the upper Darboux integral is $0$ as well:
$$\overline{\int}f=0$$
So by the definition of the Darboux integrability, $f$ is integrable, and it's integral is $0$.

**Riemann integral**

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$. If the partition is finer than $\delta$, then we have that the Riemann sum $S$ is
$$0 \leqslant S \leqslant 2 \delta $$
Which means that
$$|S-0|\leqslant |2 \delta|=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\varepsilon$$
Hence $f$ is Riemann integrable, and it's integral is $0$.